# How to manage some items of a fragment in another class from an ActionBarActivity, Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-actionbaractivity

First off, you have to forgive me, because my English is very bad.
I'll try to explain the issue:
I have an `ActionBarActivity` with two pages (`ViewPager`).
Every page has a `Fragment`.
My problem is: how to use the elements of each `Fragment` from this `ActionBarActivity`?
My code is this:

**ActionBarActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manage_devices);


        mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);
        mPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
        mActionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());}
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
        };
        mActionbar.addTab(mActionbar.newTab().setText("SENSORS").setTabListener(tabListener));
        mActionbar.addTab(mActionbar.newTab().setText("SIGNALS").setTabListener(tabListener));  


        /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
        ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
                **@Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        super.onPageSelected(position);
                        if(position == 0 & !hecho){
                        currView = mPager.getChildAt(mPager.getCurrentItem());
                        DevicesListView = (ListView) currView.findViewById(R.id.DevicesListView);
                        DevicesListView.setAdapter(DevicesAdapter);
                        DevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(DeviceOnItemClickListener);
                        hecho = true;}
                        else if(!hecho){
                            mGraph = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.graph);
                        }

                        mActionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }**

        };
        /** Setting the pageChange listener to the viewPager */
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
}
```

To get a `Listview`, I access it in `OnPageSelected`.
But this is bad for me, because I need to change a page for getting the `Listview` and build it.

**ManageFragment.java**

```
public class ManageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("","Entra");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_fragment, null);
    }
}
```

My `Listview` is in the `manage_fragment` layout.
This can help: [Illustration](http://s13.postimg.org/78pitxkwn/figure1.png)

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You can access fragments with `mPager.getAdapter().getItem(position)`

Comment: Thanks, but i need another thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your fragment already created you can just use findViewById() in your activity and just find the view you want.

So you should inform your activity that the fragment view already created through an interface for example:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnViewCreatedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

And then call the interface after Fragment's onCreateView.

Comment: Thanks, but this is my problem. I don't know when my fragment is already created. When i call listview.setAdapter() after findViewById(), i get NullPointerException.